# Generate a spaced stream of 52 random letters where each letter occurs twice

Tags: python, string, random

Well, we can generate random letters using given code snippet.

```
import random
stream_I = ''
for idx in range(0,10):
    stream_I = stream_I + ' ' + random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
print(stream_I)
```

But I was wondering how to generate lowercase alphabets 52 times given two conditions -

- They occur randomly.
- Every lowercase alphabet repeated twice.

Comment: Could you add an example output for clarification?

Comment: If I take only 5 letters 'aeiou' then an output would be 10 randomly placed letters repeated twice like -> a u a i e i o u e o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a string with all the letters you want to appear (i.e. twice the alphabet) and then just shuffle this string as if it was a list.

```
from random import shuffle
import string

orig = 2 * string.ascii_lowercase # or use 2 * 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
l = list(orig)
shuffle(l)
print ' '.join(l)  # concatenates every letter in shuffled list with a space in between
```

Comment: and instead of typing the alphabet manually, you could also use `string.ascii_lowercase` after importing the `string` module ofc.

Answer (score 4):

Just another way...

```
>>> random.sample('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 2, 52)
['s', 'z', 'c', 'j', 'f', 'k', 'i', 'h', 'f', 'u', 'n', 'u', 'x', 'g', 'v', 'o', 'g', 'x', 'n', 'h', 'q', 'm', 'l', 'k', 'q', 't', 'l', 't', 'z', 'p', 'r', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'p', 'w', 'r', 'e', 'w', 'y', 'v', 'm', 'j', 'c', 'o', 'a', 'd', 's', 'b', 'e', 'i', 'y']
```

Or if you really want to join them as a string:

```
>>> ''.join(random.sample('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 2, 52))
'idlosakvasfxzuhgerntpzgwivmuopqmybdhkycwtfnlcrjxjbeq'
```

Or if you want to print them with spaces:

```
>>> print(*random.sample('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 2, 52))
t v q n x k g o x m w y i p u t f e h k s b a v r c i j q o l z m l g p d b h y a j r n e w u c d f z s
```

---

**Edit:** And another, less pretty but much faster in my testing:

```
>>> sorted('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 2, key=lambda _: random.random())
['p', 'u', 'x', 'm', 'l', 's', 'z', 'p', 'q', 'h', 'g', 'l', 'j', 'r', 'a', 'o', 'o', 'v', 'z', 'r', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'i', 'f', 'c', 'f', 'i', 'v', 'h', 'n', 'w', 'n', 'k', 'u', 'e', 'x', 'g', 'a', 'k', 'w', 'd', 't', 'q', 'm', 'j', 'b', 's', 'e', 't', 'y', 'y']
```

Timings:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("random.sample('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 2, 52)",
           'import random', number=10**5)
4.6626533971370066
>>> timeit("sorted('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 2, key=lambda _: random.random())",
           'import random', number=10**5)
1.3866641467300198
>>> timeit("sorted('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 2, key=lambda _: random())",
           'from random import random', number=10**5)
1.2105088569363005
```

The last version is more appropriate... above I just didn't use it because the question's code did `import random`.

Looks like the big time contributor for `sample` (and `shuffle`) might be the generation of random integers, compared to random floats:

```
>>> timeit('[randrange(52) for _ in range(52)]', 'from random import randrange', number=10**5)
4.8866115645862465
>>> timeit('[random() for _ in range(52)]', 'from random import random', number=10**5)
0.3504891341253824
```

Judging by [this source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cb7fdf69ec9235cb358580f189089eaf575fb9df/Lib/random.py#L260), `sample` and `shuffle` don't actually use `randrange` but the "private" [`_randbelow`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cb7fdf69ec9235cb358580f189089eaf575fb9df/Lib/random.py#L222), but I still suspect that this same kind of overhead is the reason. At least `shuffle` can be made faster, btw. As the source code shows, we can give it a `random` function as parameter and that will then be used rather directly. Some timings:

```
>>> timeit('shuffle(a)', "from random import shuffle; a = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 2)", number=10**5)
3.863254275829604
>>> timeit('shuffle(a, random)', "from random import random, shuffle; a = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 2)", number=10**5)
1.8142924877242876
```

Comment: Huh. `sorted` being faster is really surprising.

Comment: @Ryan Yeah I was a bit surprised as well. Though `sorted` by itself should be fast. Most of the time is apparently spent on creating the random numbers, especially for integers. Added some timings now.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some timings between the working methods posted:

**Results (100,000 loops)**

```
Stefan_Pochmann: 8.842833116999827
johk95: 8.658055701991543
```

**Script used for timing**

```
from timeit import timeit

setup = """
from random import shuffle, sample
from string import ascii_lowercase
"""


methods = {
  'Stefan_Pochmann': """
sample(ascii_lowercase * 2, 52)
  """,

  'johk95': """
orig = 2 * ascii_lowercase
l = list(orig)
shuffle(l)
' '.join(l)
  """
}


for author, method in methods.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(author, timeit(stmt=method, setup=setup, number=100000)))
```